# MSMQ Message ID (as Variant)

Tags: c#, msmq

I have a MSMQ Trigger that opens a standalone executable.  The Rule Action passes the Message ID (as variant) as an invocation parameter.  I then use the message id to receive the message via Queue.ReceiveById().

Everything is working fine, but there is a little catch.  The Message ID is sent like this:

```
{5EADA58F-C733-48C3-A52A-A9FA749E7ADF}\2063
```

But the Queue.ReceiveById() function requires the Message ID to look like this (without brackets)

```
5EADA58F-C733-48C3-A52A-A9FA749E7ADF\2063
```

Can someone explain to me what the curly brackets mean?  Is there a proper way to convert this (other than just removing the brackets)?

**Edit:** I should make explicit that the Message ID is being passed as a string, since it is being passed as a command-line argument to the EXE

Comment: Message ID is a GUID. This is what a GUID format looks like. one way would be to use the .ToString() method, giving it a value to use to return the value without the curly braces. in this case it would be "D": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Message ID is of type string, so I should first parse it as a Guid, correct?  When I tried Guid.Parse(...) it throws a FormatException. I'll fiddle around a bit more - your comment is definitely helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.message.id.aspx) is a Guid plus an additional identifier:

> The identifier is composed of 20 bytes and includes two items: the machine Guid of the sending computer and a unique identifier for the message on the computer. The combination of 
>   the two items produces a message identifier that is unique on the network.

So there's no build-in parsing/reformatting function that I know of.

If you want to "parse" the guid part of the string to reformat it, you *could* do do something like:

```
string id = @"{5EADA58F-C733-48C3-A52A-A9FA749E7ADF}\2063";
string[] parts = id.Split('\\');
Guid g = Guid.Parse(parts[0]);
string newID = String.Join("\\",g.ToString("D").ToUpper(),parts[1]);
```

You might find that more "elegant", but it seems heavy to just remove a couple of curly braces.

Comment: Perfect! Is there any reason, then, that Queue.ReceiveById (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t877y0k(v=vs.110).aspx) does not accept a string with the curly brackets?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is because the ID is compared as a string and not as a Guid (since's it's a Guid plus some additional data).

Answer (score 1):

convert to string and replace the brackets with empty strings.

Here is a code sample

```
    var x = "{5EADA58F-C733-48C3-A52A-A9FA749E7ADF}\2063";
    string result = x.ToString().Replace("{",string.Empty).Replace("}",string.Empty);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, AJ.  This is pretty much what I'm doing now.  I was hoping that there was a more elegant solution, but I guess now?